# List of all users who have more than 40 documents each in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to query list of all users who have more than 40 documents each.
I've created aggregation:

```
*"aggs" : {
"user-ids" : {
"terms" : {
"field" : "user-id",
"size": 0
}
}
}*
```

where all my users in response:

```
*{
"key": 683696,
"doc_count": 4086
},

{
"key": 678776,
"doc_count": 3625
},

{
"key": 683191,
"doc_count": 3304
},

{
"key": 684065,
"doc_count": 3287
},

.....*
```

I want to leave only buckets with "doc_count" more than 40. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with the [`min_doc_count` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count). Try this:

```
{
   "aggs" : {
      "user-ids" : {
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "user-id",
            "min_doc_count": 40     <--- use this setting
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: And if I want all documents less than 40?

Comment: I can't find something like "max_doc_count"

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such setting. The only place where it was briefly mentioned was in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4983).